# How to test for the request limit on parse.com

Tags: swift, mobile, parse-platform

I am developing a mobile app (early beta) and am new to parse.
I know that if I exceed my request limit I will get an error code of 155.
Right now my traffic is basically non-existent and I try to be as request frugal as can be but I don't want to miss anything before we push to production.
Is there a (smart) way to simulate requests failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will hit the free plan request limit if you make more than 1800 requests over a period of 60 seconds. To simulate that, you can write a Cloud Function that saves/reads more than 1800 objects in a loop.

Comment: Hm, I see. So I basically exhaust my resources (e.g. on button click) and see how the app behaves. Clever.